# CSS not appearing correctly in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On my website the css is not appearing correctly only in IE9. IE8, Chrome and firefox appear just fine. Any help much appreciated!

Website: http://www.victoryit.com/

Comment: Elaborate on "Not appearing correctly". What are you trying to do? What have to tried to do it?

Comment: What are the differences? If you could update your question with screenshots, and the problematic CSS it will help others answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using cufon 1.09. There is a bug in this version which causes the fonts to disappear in IE9. Please upgrade to version 1.10. Edit: Use 1.09i as 1.10 has not been released yet.

Comment: +1 for working that out from the minimal amount of information supplied in the question.